# How can the tag wiki for "sentence-construction" be expanded?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The tag wiki for [sentence-construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-construction) currently says:

> For questions about the proper construction of sentences.

This is quite a short description, which is probably too generic to be understood. In fact, some of the questions using that tag are questions that ask for a choice between words/phrases to use.

The tag is used for questions like the following ones.

- [How to identify the essential elements of this paragraph?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/how-to-identify-the-essential-elements-of-this-paragraph) It asks how to identify the elements of a paragraph
- [What is the meaning of "Between Anne and Jack's house there is just one vacant house"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5454/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-sentence-between-anne-and-jacks-house-there-is-j) It asks about the meaning of a sentence
- [What is another way to say "have a wedding ceremony"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5389/what-is-another-way-to-say-have-a-wedding-ceremony) It asks an alternative way of saying something
- [have/has + been + 3rd verb form](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/have-has-been-3rd-verb-form) It asks about the subject of a sentence being not known
- [Is it correct to use past perfect continuous with "during"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/is-it-correct-to-use-past-perfect-continuous-with-during) It asks about the tense to use
- [Restructuring the phrase to remove repetition](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5294/restructuring-the-phrase-to-remove-repetition) It asks how to rephrase a sentence
- [Is this construction correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/is-this-construction-correct) It asks if a construction is correct
- [Is this a correct way of combining two conditional clauses?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/is-this-a-correct-way-of-combining-two-conditional-clauses) It asks how to combine two clauses to make a sentence

As I understand it, [sentence-construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-construction) should be used in questions asking, for example, about how more sentences can be rephrased and joined to make a compound/complex/complex-compound sentence. Is that its purpose? If this is the purpose, only  two of the listed questions should be using that tag.

Are there any tags that its tag wiki should reference (for example, using a sentence like "If the question is about [X] than use [the-correct-tag-for-x](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-correct-tag-for-x))?

Comment: To help facilitate discussion, here are 4 recent questions which use the [tag:sentence-construction] tag in different ways. This can help us determine if these uses are all appropriate for the tag, as well as what the tag wiki should say: [Question 1](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5228), [Question 2](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5177/), [Question 3](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5149), [Question 4](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5050/).